# Align two vector shapefiles (cells) - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-tiles, alignment

I want to align two vector shapefiles that both are represented by 100m by 100m cells. Thereby, the pink cells have to be placed on the green/yellow cells (see picture below).

[image]

I already executed the "align features"-tool with different search distances (10m, 100m, 500m, 1000m) but the output is incorrectly aligned (see picture below). Therefore, I wonder how the two vector shapefiles can be aligned correctly.

[image]

I used the same projected coordinate systems (GRS_1980_IUGG_1980_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area) for the two shapefiles and the basemap.

Comment: Not only are there corner alignment issues, but there seems to be rotation as well. You can transfer the attributes of the second polygon layer to centroid points, then intersect with the first layer, but you may need to visually confirm that the rotation isn't combined with a slightly smaller cell size to cause alignment mayhem.

Comment: How many of these do you have and are the shapes exact matches?  For those 4 polys in the first Image I'd select them and snap the bottom left corner to the target bottom left corner.  Then I'd use the Ctrl key and mouse to move the rotation anchor (x) to that lower left vertice and then rotate.  Snapping is on for all of this.

Comment: In total there are 22551 yellow/green cells and 6866 pink cells. However, there are differences in shapes and positions to the yellow/green cells, between the pink cells. The centroid points/intersect approach seems suitable for the circumstances. I tried the "transform"-tool too but this does not seem appropriate for the magnitude and/or different shapes and positions of the data.